# Check if value is undefined before render React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

I am using ([Drop Down Picker library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker)) to display categories of my data which I get from api call. I am waiting for api to fetch the data and then plan to display the categories. The problem is that I need to reformat data first and use hooks before render, but I can't get it right.

how does the data for picker looks like:

```
items={[
    {label: 'USA', value: 'usa'},
    {label: 'UK', value: 'uk'},
    {label: 'France', value: 'france'/>},
]}
```

my hooks:

```
    const [country, setCountry] = useState("0");
    const [categoryData, setCategoryData] = useState();
    const [testingCategories, setTestingCategories] = useState({
        label: null,
        value: null,
    });
```

my effect hooks and reformatting the data:

```
//this hook calls api and sets the data to categories data of my type
useEffect(() => {
    getData(api.API_GET_DEPS, setIsLoading, setCategoryData);
}, []);

//this hooks reformats the data into acceptable format for picker
useEffect(() => {
    setTestingCategories(
        categoryData
            ? categoryData.map((item) => ({
                    label: item.DEPNAME, //label
                    value: item.DEPID,   //value
              }))
            : [{ label: null, value: null }]
    );
}, [categoryData]);
```

my render of drop down:

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                    {testingCategories ? (
                        <DropDownPicker
                            dropDownMaxHeight={300}
                            placeholder="All"
                            defaultValue={country}
                            items={testingCategories}
                            containerStyle={{ height: 50 }}
                            style={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}
                            itemStyle={{
                                justifyContent: "flex-start",
                            }}
                            dropDownStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}
                            onChangeItem={(item) => {
                                console.log("changed");
                            }}
                            onOpen={() => setContainerOpacity(0.1)}
                            onClose={() => setContainerOpacity(1)}
                            labelStyle={{
                                fontSize: 16,
                                color: colors.dark,
                                fontWeight: "600",
                            }}
                            arrowSize={25}
                            arrowColor={colors.dark}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <></>
                    )}
```

I get an error that drop down picker can't match the `defaultValue` with any label in testingCategories because it is null and haven't loaded yet. I suppose I am using setter wrong because I can't check whether `testingCategories`'s first element was loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found this issue of the library https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/pull/205, if it helps. Maybe you don't have the latest version

Comment: Yes! Thats what I saw just now ...7 days ago a merged commit. Now I am getting the data correctly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have a typing mismatch between your `useState` definition and where you use `setTestingCategories` later.

In your `useState`, you define the initial value as a singular object:

```
useState({
        label: null,
        value: null,
    });
```

However, what you probably want is an empty array:

```
useState([]);
```

I would also change your current line `[{ label: null, value: null }]` to just be an empty array `[]`.

Then, your `testingCategories` flag will work, because `testingCategories` will initially be an array of length 0, which will fail the truthiness test.

Comment: Did you follow this step: `I would also change your current line [{ label: null, value: null }] to just be an empty array []`? If you log testingCateories.length, what's the value?

Comment: yes, my useEffect on change of `categoryData` doesn't even go through...drop down picker goes to render right away and throws undefined error on label because useState([]) doesn't have `label` property in it I suppose

Comment: I guess I'm confused about where the `undefined` error is then. Can you create a Snack where this can be reproduced?